# Updating Particular Key/Values in a Hash Table - Redis C# .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis

I am new to Redis and I am trying to do the usual, which is convert a single SQL table to Redis.  More specifically, after doing some reading, I came across `hset`, which I translated into C# .Net Core with `StackExchange.Redis`.

I also came across Sorted Sets, which after reading stated they would be necessary for searching for specific things, but after finding some example code [Here](http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/redis-sorted-sets-datatype/) it doesn't seem to be what I am looking for (unless I'm incorrect)

Basically, I have an API that takes in 4 parameters, a `device` no, `input` no, `state` (0 or 1) and a `datetime`.  Once the `device` and `input` have been looked up, the `state` will updated in accordance with the parameter.  E.g. `device` 1, `input` 12, `state` 1, `datetime` "xxx".

My code so far is this; however, this only pertains to one row/hash entry, there will be a total of 12 `inputs` for each `device` and a total of 16 `devices`, so there will be a total of 192 rows/hash Entries.

```
            string state = "state:1";

            HashEntry[] states =
            {
                new HashEntry("id", 1),
                new HashEntry("device", 1),
                new HashEntry("input", 1),
                new HashEntry("state", 0),
                new HashEntry("when", "2019-10-23 14:22:48.5174055 +01:00")

            };

            db.HashSet(state, states);

            var allStates = db.HashGetAll(state);

            foreach(var item in allStates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name}, {item.Value}");
            }
```

Such code will be in some form of loop in order to fulfil the 192 rows/hash entries, but I thought I would code this just to start.  So I thought I would seek some guidance, as the way in which I am approaching this could be incorrect, or, I am missing something such as a Sorted Set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashes are a good place to start, but I would suggest using different keys to segment your data rather than having to iterate through all entries. Set a new key for each input of a device (192 keys in total):

```
device1:input1 
device1:input2
device1:input3
...
```

Each key would then store your hash entries. To update a field for a particular key, you would only need to execute a single hash-set command, for example:

```
db.HashSet("device6:input2", "when", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Or to update multiple fields:

```
db.HashSet("device6:input2", new HashEntry[] 
{ 
    new HashEntry("state", 1), 
    new HashEntry("when", DateTime.Now.ToString())
});
```

If you just wanted to retrieve a device's data, it's pretty easy as well:

```
db.HashGet("device6:input2", "your-field-name"); // gets a single field's value
db.HashGetAll("device6:input2"); // gets the values from all fields
```

This will give you the simplest implementation and will save you from having to iterate through many entries.

Comment: Great!  That seems to make sense to me.  I think with the `update` rest call I could do something like this `db.HashSet($"device{device}:input{input}", "state", state, "when", some-date-time)` if the call was something like `/api/updateState/1/7/1/some-date-time`